# How can i add multiple sticker in imageview swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, uiimage

I am working on photoEditing app and i need to add sticker on it, i have one view which name is viewImageBackground and inside this view i have one image view. Using following code i am adding stickers on Image view.

```
    if selectedPhotos == "Goodies" {

            switch indexPath.row {

            case 0:
                addStickers(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Goodies-1.png"))

                break
            case 1:
                addStickers(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Goodies-2.png"))

                break
            case 2:
                addStickers(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Goodies-3.png"))

                break
            case 3:
                addStickers(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Goodies-4.png"))

                break

            default:
                break
            }
        }
```

Add Sticker function

```
    func addStickers(_ imgImage: UIImage) {

    hideTextButtons()

    textView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    textView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    viewImgBackground.addSubview(textView!)

    //Content view

    gesture = "Stickers"

    var imgSticker  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 80, height: 80))
    imgSticker.image = imgImage
    imgSticker.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill

    imgSticker.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imgSticker.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true

    textView?.addSubview(imgSticker)

    deleteView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
    deleteView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    deleteView?.image = UIImage(named: "close_gold.png")
    deleteView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.singleTap))
    deleteView?.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
    textView?.addSubview(deleteView!)

    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
    panGesture.delegate = self

    pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinchGesture(_:)))
    pinchGesture.delegate = self

    textView?.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    textView?.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)

    rotateView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (textView?.frame.size.height)! - 25, width: 25, height: 25))
    rotateView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    rotateView?.image = UIImage(named: "button_01.png")
    rotateView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView?.addSubview(rotateView!)

    let panRotateGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.rotateViewPanGesture))
    rotateView?.addGestureRecognizer(panRotateGesture)
    panRotateGesture.require(toFail: panRotateGesture)

    let snapshotImage = UIImage.imageWithView(view: viewImgBackground)
    count += 1

    logoImages.append(snapshotImage)


}
```

now my view is look like following image

[image]

now issue is that i need to add multiple stickers with gesture using this code my condition is satisfied 50% sticker is added on image view with gesture but i need to add multiple stickers which means whenever i click on each stickers new imageview with stickers needs to be added but this code will added only one sticker and replacing sticker inside view. how do i achieve it ?

**NOTE:** whenever i click on reset button i need to remove all this stickers so here u have declared imgSticker as a local variable which is not worth it so what can i do for adding multiple stickers on Image view.

Please Help,
Thanks!